# SSRS - Horizontal Strip Lines not showing in the chart

Tags: reporting-services, line, strip

I am trying to plot a static value of `3%` horizontally in a line chart using `StripLines` property. I could see the strip line showing in the report designer but it doesn't show me when I preview the report.

Below are my strip line property settings -

[image]

[image]

The final result does not give me the stripline at the desired location in the graph -

[image]

Am I missing any property setting here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What format are the percentages in your dataset? What I mean is... If you have 10% showing on the chart, is that stored as 10 or 0.1 in the dataset. If its the latter, then your strip line needs to be set at 0.03

Comment: Yes, I missed considering the distribution of my percentage values in the Y- axis. 
I set the Strip Line to 0.03 and it worked. Thank you !!